# Escaping Regex to get Valid JSON

Tags: json, schema

In my schema, I want to recognize certain patterns to restrict the type of data that a user can enter.  I use regex to restrict what a user can enter, but the regex get flagged when I try to validate the JSON using an online validator like this [one](http://jsonlint.com/).

Is there a way to make the validator ignore the regex special chars that are disagreeing with it, but still keep the regex?

The weird thing is that the validator only trips up on certain instances.  For instance, it flags the second and not the first instance of regex despite them being identical here:

```
            "institutionname": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "institution name",
                "label": "name",
                "input-type": "text",
                "pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$"
            },
            "bio": {
                "type": "string",
                "label": "bio",
                "input-type": "text",
                "pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$",
                "help-box": "tell us about yourself"
            },
```

Comment: You need to escape the backslash by prefixing it with another backslash:`"^[A-Za-z0-9\\s]+$"`. JSONLint flagged both instances when I tried it.

Comment: How would I escape this:                     "pattern": "^[A-Za-z\s]+[^0-9A-Z+\\\_\-\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\+\=\{\}\[\]\;\:\'\"\<\>\,\.\?\/\|]$"

Comment: Double escape the all the `\\`, as in my example. A lot of those characters you have escaped are inside a character class, so don't need escaping anyway

Comment: Sorry, but how and why do I need to escape "?

Comment: You escape a character by putting a `\` in front of it.  The reason you do this is because the interpreter needs to know when a character is being 'special'---ie, indicating some kind of command to it, or being 'literal,' telling you that it's really being a slash.  In JSON, if the machine sees a backslash, it assumes that's telling it the next character is part of a special command, like "\n " saying "insert a new line."  When you escape a slash, you say "no, really, I want a literal slash here, the next character coming up is not special"

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Its just the slashes that are messing up the validation you could encode them using `%5C` which is the hex encoding of `\` or what Mike W says you could double escape like `\\`  and then you could just decode them when you want to use them

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me. `%5C` doesn't work well with a linter. Plus manually doing it is a job. How about a very long regex -

`^(([^<>()[\\]\\.,;:\\s@\"]+(\\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$`

So, please don't kill yourself and head to this get this done - https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html#ad-output

In case the link doesn't work in future, please find some other online tool :)