# Regex \\s understanding

Tags: regex, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I m trying to understand Json schema definition of below snippet,

```
  "translated_string": {
    "description": "A translated string",
    "type": "string",
    "minLength": 1,
    "not": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^\\s+$"
    }
  },
```

Questions:

1. what does `\\s` represents.
2. some explanation of snippet by giving some examples valid schema.

Comment: `\\s` represents an [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17597400/4607733) space metacharacter (see [Shorthand Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)). What can't you understand about the snippet?

Comment: @horcrux some explanation of snippet by giving some examples for valid schemas and not valid schemas

Comment: "^\\s+$" is "Any non empty string that is only whitespace", but the validator is taking the NOT of that (so anything BUT that)

Comment: Why down vote for the question?

Answer (score 3):

In regex syntax, `\s` is a metacharacter representing a whitespace (see [Shorthand Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)). In some languages you need to double escape it because of the slash (so `\\s`).

Lets analyze the regex:

- `^` is the begin of the string
- `\\s` is the space
- `+` is an operator meaning "one or more"
- `$` is the end of the string

So the pattern matches the strings composed only of at least one space and nothing more.

Let's now analyze the snippet:

- `"description"` is just the description associated to the `translated_string` property
- `"type": "string"` means that in the JSON you can only use a string value for the `translated_string` property
- `"not"` means that the following is *not* permitted:

  - `"pattern": "^\\s+$"` is the regex above (so it must *not* be matched)

Note that the snippet is equivalent to:

```
"translated_string": {
  "description": "A translated string",
  "type": "string",
  "not": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^\\s*$"
  }
},
```

(where the `*` operator means "zero or more")
or even simplier:

```
"translated_string": {
  "description": "A translated string",
  "type": "string",
  "pattern": "^\\S+$"
},
```

(where `\\S` is anything but a space)

So, the following JSON are **correct**:

```
"translated_string": "l"
"translated_string": " l"
"translated_string": " l "
"translated_string": "  l "
```

While the following JSON are **not correct**:

```
"translated_string": ""
"translated_string": " "
"translated_string": "  "
"translated_string": 1
"translated_string": [ SOMETHING ]
"translated_string": { SOMETHING }
```