# Best way to store dicts, regex and variables in external file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, configuration-files

For configuration purposes, if I store an "easy" regex in a `JSON` file and load it into my Python program, it works just fine.

```
{
    "allow": ["\/word\/.*"],
    "follow": true
},
```

If I store a more complex regex in a JSON file, the same Python program fails.

```
{
    "allow": ["dcp\=[0-9]+\&dppp\="],
    "follow": true
},
```

That's the code that loads my JSON file:

```
src_json = kw.get('src_json') or 'sources/sample.json'
self.MY_SETTINGS = json.load(open(src_json))
```

and the error is usually the same, pointing my online searches to the fact, that [regular expressions should not be stored in JSON](https://json.org/) files.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 22 column 38 (char 801)
```

YAML files seem to have [similar limitations](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2770814), so I shouldn't got down that way I guess.

Now, I've stored my expression inside a dict in a separate file:

```
mydict = {"allow": "com\/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*\?skid\="}
```

and load it from my program file:

```
exec(compile(source=open('expr.py').read(), filename='expr.py', mode='exec'))

print(mydict)
```

Which works and would be fine with me - but it looks a bit ... special ... with exec and compile.

Is there any reason not to do it in this way?
Is there a better way to store complex data structures and regular expressions in external files which I can open / use in my program code?

Comment: Consider using Python's `pickle` module. Also see [Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder).

Comment: Note that you should use the `r` string prefix for regex expressions (and not doing so might actually be the cause of some of your storage problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, regular expressions can be stored as JSON, but need to be stored as valid JSON. This is the cause of your `JSONDecodeError` in the example.

There are other answers here on SO, that explain how to properly encode/decode regex as valid JSON, such as:
[Escaping Regex to get Valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597238/escaping-regex-to-get-valid-json)

Now, the other pieces of your question start to go into more best practices and opinions.

- Can you use JSON for dicts, regex, and variables?

  - Yes
- Is JSON ideal?

  - Depends on your use case
  - [What is JSON and why would I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

As you've seen, you certainly can declare & use variables from other files:

`test_regex.py`

```
my_dict = {'allow': 'com\\/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*\\?skid\\='}
```

`script.py`

```
from test_regex import mydict
mydict
{'allow': 'com\\/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*\\?skid\\='}
```

However, this is a pretty different feeling use case. In our JSON example, the information is set in a way that we expect it to be more easily configurable - different JSON files could be used (perhaps for different environment configurations) each with different regex. In this example, we don't assume configurability but instead the `test_regex` is used for separation of concerns and readability.

Comment: You are right but that "valid JSON" is no use in the case of a regex pattern because it changed.

Answer (score 2):

The link you indicate is the JSON specification. It doesn't say anything about regular expressions as far I can tell.

What you seem to be doing is taking a working regular expression and pasting that in your JSON file for (re-) use. And that is not always working because some of the things have to be escaped for the JSON to be valid.

There is however a simple way of inserting the regular expression into the JSON file, **with the appropriate escapes**, by making a small Python program that will take the regular expression as a commandline parameter and  then `json.dump()` the JSON file, or, alternatively, load-update-dump the file with the new regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing your dictionary in a .py file you can import the variable directly as long as the file can be found [in your `PYTHONPATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath) or you use a [relative import](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).

For instance if I make a .py file called `expr.py` and `PYTHONPATH` includes the folder it's in.

The contents of the file (same as your example):

```
mydict = {"allow": "com\/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*\?skid\="}
```

Then I can run this from an interpreter or another script

```
>>> from expr import mydict
>>> mydict
{'allow': 'com\\/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*\\?skid\\='}
```

No need to mess around with `open()` and `exec` unless i'm missing something here. I use this approach to storing regexes because you can store `re.compile` objects directly.

if I change the file to:

```
import re
mydict = {"allow": re.compile(r"com\/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*\?skid\=")}
```

I can do:

```
>>> from expr import mydict
>>> print(mydict)
{'allow': re.compile('com\\/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*\\?skid\\=')}
>>> print(mydict["allow"].pattern)
com\/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*\?skid\=
>>> print(mydict["allow"].match("com/x-x?skid="))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='com/x-x?skid='>
```

if the file has a silly amount of regexes the automatic sorting of the variables under the script name could help with organisation too:

file:

```
import re
mydict = {"allow": re.compile(r"com\/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*\?skid\=")}
easydict = {"allow": re.compile(r"\/word\/.*"), "follow": True}
complexdict = {"allow": re.compile(r"dcp\=[0-9]+\&dppp\="), "follow": True}
```

interpreter:

```
>>> import expr
>>> print(expr.easydict["allow"].pattern)
\/word\/.*
>>> print(expr.complexdict["allow"].match("dcp=11&dppp="))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='dcp=11&dppp='>
>>> print(expr.mydict)
{'allow': re.compile('com\\/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*\\?skid\\=')}
```