# What is the correct pattern to validate the data time in json schema?

Tags: json, regex, json-schema-validator

Want to have a correct pattern for below

18-11-2023 16:03:22

DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MM:SS

I am using below pattern and it works fine but if I pass date or month as single digit it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
"pattern": "^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])-\\d\\d\\d\\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blocks single digit days and months - see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MSEnwx/1).

I only removed the double `\\` to make it regex101 compatible.

```
^(([012][0-9])|(3[01]))-([0][1-9]|1[012])-\\d\\d\\d\\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]$
```

In json-schema each `\` has to be escaped by another `\`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597238/escaping-regex-to-get-valid-json/17597400#17597400)

Comment: If I remove that escaped character it gives an error in parsing the JSON. Added a pic to show that.

Comment: You need to reinstate the escape \ but the regex **works** with single digit day and month. Updated answer to clarify.

Comment: John, I want it to fail if single digit day or month was provided. It is currently passing with that so wanted to know how to fix this.

Comment: @Maddy - I have fixed the regex to fail on single digit day and month.